# Scanf does not work as expected

Tags: c++, scanf, cin

I tried to compare `std::cin` and `scanf`, I expected them to have same behavior, but actually not:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
  int i;
  cin>>i;
  return 0;
}
```

This receives an input from user, no problem.
But

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
  int i;
  scanf("%d\n",&i);
  return 0;
}
```

I input a integer, program doesn't terminate even if I press "enter" multiple times, unless I enter another integer number.

Note there's an "\n" in scanf's format string.
So I tried to add one statement

```
printf("%d\n", i);
```

Well it prints out the 1st number I just input. This is correct but weird, why after scanf, the program requires me to enter any character rather then `\n`, to exit the program?

I tried both VC and GCC, same problem. What is that `\n` indicating?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`scanf("%d\n",&i);` is equivalent to `std::cin >> i >> std::ws;`.

If you want the same behaviour for `scanf`, remove `\n`: `scanf("%d",&i);`

This is caused by the fact that any whitespace character in `scanf` means *"skip input until non-whitespace is found"*

Answer (score 3):

```
  scanf("%d\n",&i);
```

Let's read the [manpage of scanf :](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/)

> **Whitespace character:** the function will read and ignore any whitespace characters encountered before the next non-whitespace character (whitespace characters include spaces, newline and tab characters -- see isspace). A single whitespace in the format string validates any quantity of whitespace characters extracted from the stream (including none).

What it means is scanf will search for a integer followed by an optionnal whitespace. that's why he's waiting for you to use two times enter. If you used `"%d\n\n"`, it'll have to be three times. And so on.

If you want only an interger, use       `scanf("%d",&i);`